# Javascript array sorting change index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hy,

When i sort my array, it change my index :

```
Myarray.sort(function (a, b) {
    //sort : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort2.shtml
    var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB = b.name.toLowerCase()
    if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
        return -1;
    if (nameA > nameB)
        return 1;
    return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
});
```

before my sort :

```
array : "86", "85", "89"
```

after my sort :

```
array : "0", "1", "2"
```

I want to know if it's normal.

And if it's normal how i can change that ?

Thanks, for your answers.

Comment: What are those "before my sort / after my sort" values? Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can better understand your issue?

Comment: it's the id of my object on my array.
I add my object like this : 

     Myarray[id] = myObject;

in myObject i have :

     {"target_area" : { "name_area" : "zzzzzzzzzz"}};

Comment: here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/G3gc3/1/

Comment: Well, you are sorting an array so of course the indices change. To answer your question: Yes, this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> before my sort, `array : "86", "85", "89"`

Looks like you have a sparse array: An array of length `90` with items at the indices `85`, `86` and `89`.

> after my sort, `array : "0", "1", "2"`. Is this normal?

Yes. Non-existent properties (`0`-`84`, `87`, `88`) are ignored by [`sort`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.11). From the spec:

> ***NOTE 1***: Because non-existent property values always compare greater than `undefined`  property values, and `undefined` always compares greater than any other value, `undefined` property values always sort to the end of the result, followed by non-existent property values.

> how i can change that ?

You cannot. However, there's no reason to have anything else than that, as you wanted to *sort* your array, which means reordering the items. Array indices are no ids. If your objects should have ids, make them properties:

```
var myArray = [
    {"id":"86", "target_area": {"name_area": "Loic"}},
    {"id":"85", "target_area": {"name_area": "aaaaaaaa"}},
    {"id":"81", "target_area": {"name_area": "zzzzzzzzzz"}}
];
```

Of course, there are workarounds like copying the values to a different array, sorting that and moving them back into the sparse array - see [javascript sort sparse array keep indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12137690/1048572). You don't seem to need that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is behaving as expected. The `sort` function will always sort the array starting at 0. When it finds elements (or occupied indices), it will recursively shift it's index to the front of the array until it matches another element which has a *higher* value.

If you want to retain the indices, you need to create a function which 'stores' the indices previously occupied.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3gc3/3/) which does this.

**Function**

```
function sortToIndices(arr){
    var occupiedIndices = [],
        objectCollection = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != null){ // You may want to make this condition more strict
            occupiedIndices.push(i);
            objectCollection.push(arr[i]);
        }
    };

    objectCollection.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.target_area.name_area.toLowerCase(), 
            nameB = b.target_area.name_area.toLowerCase();
            if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
                return -1;
            if (nameA > nameB)
                return 1;
            return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
    });

    for (i = 0; i < occupiedIndices.length; i++) {
        arr[occupiedIndices[i]] = objectCollection[i];
    };       
}
```

Comment: Thx very much. I gonna try that soon